# Likelihood function uder Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, maximum-likelihood

Say we have a set of observations $\{X_i : i=0,...,N\}$ from a simple Brownian motion (scaled Winner process) $$dX_t = \sigma dW_t .$$ If we discretise this to

$$X_i-X_{i-1} = \sigma\sqrt{\Delta}Z_i$$

with $Z_i \sim N(0,1)$ then the likelihood function is a product of

$$L_i(\sigma | \{Z_i\}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{Z_i^2}{2}\right)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(X_i-X_{i-1})^2}{2\sigma^2\Delta}\right) .$$

However, if we discretise this to

$$X_i-X_{i-1} = Y_i$$

with $Y_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2\Delta)$ then the likelihood function is a product of

$$L_i(\sigma | \{Y_i\}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2\Delta}}\exp\left(-\frac{Y_i^2}{2\sigma^2\Delta}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2\Delta}}\exp\left(-\frac{(X_i-X_{i-1})^2}{2\sigma^2\Delta}\right) .$$

So there seems to be a difference in the denominator under the square root depending on whether I choose $Z_i$ or $Y_i$, which doesn't seem right to me as it would presumably lead to different estimates of $\sigma$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Everything is right. The actual issue here is that maximum likehood estimation is _not_ preserved under transformations.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Thank you for your message. So, is there a "correct" way to estimate $\sigma$ in the above? Put it another way, how does one choose the estimator in situations like this? Thanks

Comment: Usually we choose $Y_i$, since it's unlikely to be possible to compute $Z_i$ without a priori knowledge of $\sigma$.

Comment: @CaveJohnson But we don't actually need to compute $Y_i$ since in the end both are represented by $X_i - X_{i-1}$ in the likelihoods and $\sigma$ appears in both likelihoods.

Comment: By a maximum likelihood estimation given observation $\xi$, we mean a value of $\sigma$ such that $L(\sigma\mid\xi)$ is maximized. This is just the _definition_. In our case, only $X_i-X_{i-1}$, i.e. $Z_i$, can be observed.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Sorry, I am not sure I follow. I can maximise both likelihoods above (for $Y$ and for $Z$) by using the last expression for each and finding $\sigma$ (analytically or numerically) which gives the maximum using only the observable differences $X_i - X_{i-1}$.